# Show recent select queries on Firebird database file

Tags: monitoring, log, firebird

Is there a way to log or query the n recent SELECT queries to an FDB database file? I have already tried using the MON$ and RDB$ tables but I didn't find anything useful.

Comment: Take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30253010/470530)!

Answer (score 1):

There is no history of queries in Firebird. As indicated by Verace in the comments, you can look at [one of my answers on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30253010/466862) that provides an alternative: using the trace API.

However the trace API requires active monitoring, which has some overhead. As an alternative you could also look at [FBScanner](https://ib-aid.com/en/fbscanner-firebird-scanner/), which acts as a proxy between Firebird and your client, which allows it to register the prepared and executed queries.